# Как отфильтровать сложный многомерный массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет. Имеется массив вида

```
    $array = array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
        'expirationDate' => '1671845325,529',
        'hostOnly' => false,
        'httpOnly' => false,
        'name' => 'SID',
        'path' => '/',
        'sameSite' => 'unspecified',
        'secure' => false,
        'session' => false,
        'storeId' => '0',
        'value' => '4wdY_czyOdfgd5hfgh34h870uuj7LRagEE53hV3_gghetrxC-717H5-p5ycfP_uJomw.',
        'priority' => 'high',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
        'expirationDate' => '1671845325,529',
        'hostOnly' => false,
        'httpOnly' => true,
        'name' => '__Secure-3PSID',
        'path' => '/',
        'sameSite' => 'norestriction',
        'secure' => true,
        'session' => false,
        'storeId' => '1',
        'value' => '4wdY_czyKmbn75De2Z13H8iMhL8h870uuj7LRagEE53hV3_guZ2W7Qf-y8NKsjpLmuNkEAw.',
        'priority' => 'high',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
        'expirationDate' => '1671845325,529',
        'hostOnly' => false,
        'httpOnly' => false,
        'name' => 'SID',
        'path' => '/',
        'sameSite' => 'unspecified',
        'secure' => false,
        'session' => false,
        'storeId' => '0',
        'value' => '4wdY_czyOdfgd5hfgh34h870uuj7LRagEE53hV3_gghetrxC-717H5-p5ycfP_uJomw.',
        'priority' => 'high',
      ),
    );
```

Очевидно, что в массиве элементы 0 и 2 равны (одинаковые массивы).
Как лучше всего отфильтровать массив, оставив в нём только уникальные элементы? Иными словами привести его к виду:

```
    $array = array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
        'expirationDate' => '1671845325,529',
        'hostOnly' => false,
        'httpOnly' => false,
        'name' => 'SID',
        'path' => '/',
        'sameSite' => 'unspecified',
        'secure' => false,
        'session' => false,
        'storeId' => '0',
        'value' => '4wdY_czyOdfgd5hfgh34h870uuj7LRagEE53hV3_gghetrxC-717H5-p5ycfP_uJomw.',
        'priority' => 'high',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
        'expirationDate' => '1671845325,529',
        'hostOnly' => false,
        'httpOnly' => true,
        'name' => '__Secure-3PSID',
        'path' => '/',
        'sameSite' => 'norestriction',
        'secure' => true,
        'session' => false,
        'storeId' => '1',
        'value' => '4wdY_czyKmbn75De2Z13H8iMhL8h870uuj7LRagEE53hV3_guZ2W7Qf-y8NKsjpLmuNkEAw.',
        'priority' => 'high',
      )
    );
```

Встроенная функция php

```
$clean = array_unique ( $array );
```

здесь не работает и выдаёт ошибки:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>52</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>52</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>52</b><br />
```

Есть решение у данной задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для осуществлении фильтрации массива на уникальные элементы, Вам необходимо передать флаг `SORT_REGULAR`

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR )
```

По умолчанию используется `SORT_STRING`, по этому каждый элемент в Вашем примере интерпретатор преобразовывал в строку(что гласит соответственно ошибка), а уже после сортирует и сравнивает.

Виды сортировок флагов:

```
SORT_REGULAR - нормальное сравнение элементов (типы не меняются)
SORT_NUMERIC - элементы сравниваются как числа
SORT_STRING - элементы сравниваются как строки
SORT_LOCALE_STRING - сравнивает элементы как строки, с учетом текущей локали.
```

Кстати, функция `array_unique` удаляет не уникальные элементы сохраняющая ключи. Это значит, что в массиве возможно будут пробелы. Чтобы исправить это, используйте след. код:

```
array_values(array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR ));
```